# Why I don't see ::after and ::before element without display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, inline, pseudo-element

### **ABOUT PROBLEM**

I tried to make hamburger-menu from [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/dAIVbLrAb_U). In 6.23 minute we had a problem with displaying `::after` and `::before` element - without `display: flex` on `.hamburger-menu` class we don't see black spaces. In tutorial I heard we have the problem because `.hamburger-menu` is inline by default. **I don't understand why we can see black elements only when parent class is flex or grid (I check) or when I fill `content` property with the text.** Even if I set it to block element I don't see the change.

### **CODE**

```css
.hamburger-menu{
   display:flex;
}

.hamburger-menu:after,
.hamburger-menu:before,
.hamburger-menu input{
    width:60px;
    height:7px;
    content:"";
    background-color:rgb(30,30,30);
    border-radius:10000px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <label class="hamburger-menu">
       <input type="checkbox"></label>
    </label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your pseudo elements (which should be written as `::before` and `::after`, btw. - double colon) themselves are inline by default - and therefor width and height _must_ not have any effect, and without any `content` property specified either, there simply _is_ nothing to render. Making the label a flex container, makes the pseudo elements themselves flex items, and on _those_ width and height are allowed to have an effect.

Comment: You have malformed HTML: You have 2 `</label>` tags but only 1 `<label>`.